# Display only the Checked Items in the CheckBoxList using C#.Net:

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have One CheckBox above the CheckBoxList and its Text as "Show only Selected Items".

My CheckBoxList has 10 items and three items as Selected.

But when I Check the CheckBox, I want to display only the selected three items in the CheckBoxList.
When I uncheck the CheckBox, I want to display all the 10 items and three items as selected.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the checked event of checkbox of "Show only Selected Items", do loop and check which is checked and if checkbox of checkboxlist is not selected then remove/visible false that item from checkboxlist.

```
void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(chk.Items[i].Selected != true)
        chk.visibility = chk.checked;
}
```

Comment: so you copy what i wrote almost to the letter, including my original syntax error of checkbox1.checked; and you get the credit... interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your aspx page for each checkbox needs the onchecked change

```
  <asp:CheckBox OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" runat="server" />
```

Your code behind.

```
  void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
    //foreach checkbox in your checkbox list
    //checkbox.visibility = checkbox.checked;
  }
```

Something like this... this is kind of pseudo code but hopefully the logic behind it is what you're looking for.